# Check Prime Number, in python. logic confusion

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

I found this code in a website for checking prime number

```
def isPrime(number):
    if (number <= 1):
        return False
    elif (number <= 3):
        return True
    elif (number % 2 == 0 or number % 3 == 0):
        return False
    
    i = 5
    while(i * i <= number):
        if (number % i == 0 or number % (i + 2) == 0):
            return False

        i += 6

    return True
```

but I can't understand the logic of `if` statement under while loop, that is `if (number % i == 0 or number % (i + 2) == 0)`
why need `i+2`??? when `i` is even, `i+2` is also even and odd while `i` is odd. So, why need to check for `i+2`???

Comment: Short answer, because the while loop increments `i` by `6`.

Comment: we check at 5,7 then 11,13, then 17,19, then 23,25(not check at 25 since already checked at 5) then 29,31 etc ect

Comment: This is a speedup on the naive algorithm for primality, based on the fact that if p is prime then p % 6 must be either 1 or 5, so only need to check 2 out of every 6 numbers.

Comment: Thank you so much, bro, you got me and gave me an easy explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Except for 2 and 3, all prime numbers are of the form 6n±1.  This code checks for 2 and 3 explicitly and then checks higher numbers in pairs: 6n-1, 6n+1, starting with 5.  So it checks 5, 7 then 11, 13 then 17, 19 and so on.  It steps 6 between pairs and steps 2 within each pair.  Doing it this way avoids ever having to check multiples of 2 or 3.

Answer (score 1):

i starts from 5, so adding 2 means taking in count only evens numbers.
It makes the check faster.

Comment: s/even/odd (for those of us who remember ed and vi in Unix).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out if a number is prime or not, here is a short sample

```
# Check if a positive integer number is a prime number. Check only till square root +1.

import math

def isPrime(n):
  if ( n > 3 ):
    if (n % 2 == 0):
      return False
    for i in range(3, math.isqrt(n), 2):
      if (n % i == 0):
        return False
    return True
  else:
    return True
```